# gnome desktop not working after a new Ubuntu 20.04 and Brave install

Tags: gnome, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop

I have to install Ubuntu again, and to my surprise, the gnome extension is not working. I keep getting this message:

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.

I do have my gnome extension installed on my **Brave** browser. I installed Brave from **Ubuntu Software**, so it is a snap package.

I think I did all I need to run it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

then

```
#  Ubuntu 20.04
sudo apt-get install libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor
```

then I bounce the GNOME Shell by typing:

```
Alt+F2, type r then Enter.
```

My extension is not working. I am still getting the message as seen in this pic

[image]

**Please let me know how to access my gnome extensions. I just want to install some basic extensions. Thanks.**

Comment: Have you looked through [this](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/) useful reference? Do extensions work if you use Firefox or Chromium?

Comment: Indeed, with Firefox I can have access to gnome extensions... that would do for me. Thank you @User24601 !

Comment: I've added that as an answer with further information about Brave which if you can [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) others with the same issue can benefit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a useful reference [here](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/) about using GNOME Shell Extensions.

It was necessary to follow these guidelines after installing 20.04.1 to get the extensions to work in my system with the same error message using the default Firefox installation.

On the other hand, there is a reference [here](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017909112-How-can-I-add-extensions-to-Brave-) from the Brave Help Center which gives further information on adding Extensions to their browser.

Comment: I had to manually download the archive and place it in the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` (because for me the install prompt was not showing up)